# error in playing audio in web page even after applying auto click function using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried to bypass the uncaught DOM exception using auto click of button when page load. but still audio not working

```
<div class="hidden">
    <button class="btn btn-danger" id="samplebtn">testing</button>
    <audio id="myAudio" >
        <source src="../../sounds/hiccup.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){


        $('#samplebtn').click(function(){
            var notif_sound = document.getElementById("myAudio");
            notif_sound.play();
            alert("hi");

        });
        document.getElementById("samplebtn").click();
```

Comment: `I tried to bypass the uncaught DOM exception` maybe this is why it isn't working. Better to fix than to bypass

Comment: but i need to play the sound once the page load because that will be used as the notification sound

Comment: what i mean in by pass is. google chrome doesnt allow auto play of audio anymore. so what i did is on page load i trigger the button to be clicked and that will trigger to play the sound.